# Manipulating POST Data from Controller in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm working on a project with a goal of POSTing a string and returning every third character of that string. The project is built in Ruby/Rails.

I have the (hacky) logic down for getting that third element out, putting it in a new string, and saving this new string it with the new object in the database, but my issue at the moment is that all of this logic is done in the Controller. I'd really like to follow MVC, so my goal is to get all of this logic into the Model.

Currently, the `*params` and `create` methods in my Controller look like this:

```
Class TestController < ApplicationController

...

def create
     new_output_string = params[:input_string].split("")
     final_output_string_array = []
     counter = 1
     new_output_string.each do |letter|
      if counter % 3 == 0
        final_output_string_array.append(letter)
      end      
      counter = counter + 1
    end
    final_output_string = final_output_string_array.join("")
    @test = Test.create(
      input_string: params[:input_string], 
      output_string: final_output_string
    )
    render json: @test
  end

  def test_params
    params.require(:test).permit(:input_string, :output_string)
  end
```

So you can see that all of the logic for manipulating this data is in the Controller. I tried writing a method `make_output_string` in the model:

```
Class Test < ApplicationRecord

    def self.make_output_string()
        new_output_string = params[:input_string].split("")
        final_output_string_array = []
        counter = 1
        new_output_string.each do |letter|
          if counter % 3 == 0
            final_output_string_array.append(letter)
          end      
          counter = counter + 1
        end
        @final_output_string = final_output_string_array.join("")
    end
```

I hoped that this would manipulate the data before the `create` action (I tried using `before_create` etc.) calling `before_create`, and referencing the method in the controller's create method, but I either get no result or an `undefined method` error.

How can I move my logic into the Model so that it can handle the manipulation/creation of the parameters?

Comment: Thats a pretty overcomplicated way of doing `params[:input_string].split("").each_with_index.filter_map {|l, index| l if index % 3 == 0 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom setter for input_string on the Model and make it save both input_string and output_string.

```
Class Test < ApplicationRecord

    def input_string=(input_string)
        super(input_string)
        self.output_string = generate_output(input_string)
    end


    private

    def generate_output(input_string)
      new_output_string = input_string.split("")
      final_output_string_array = []
      counter = 1
      new_output_string.each do |letter|
        if counter % 3 == 0
          final_output_string_array.append(letter)
        end      
        counter = counter + 1
      end
      final_output_string_array.join("")
    end
end
```

Then your controller would be like the following.

```
Class TestController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @test = Test.create(input_string: params[:input_string])
    render json: @test
  end

  def test_params
    params.require(:test).permit(:input_string, :output_string)
  end
end
```

Comment: wow thank you so much! That worked perfectly. Definitely interested and will be looking into your solution more :)